# Creating new Angular application

Tags: angular

Me encuentro con este error sin poder solucionarlo por varios días.

`$ npm install
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for source-map@^0.6.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular/compiler-cli'
npm ERR! notarget`

Las dependencias son:

A continuación el package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"   },  





"devDependencies": {
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.14",
 "@angular/cli": "~8.3.14",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
 "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
 "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
 "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
 "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
 "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
 "karma": "~4.1.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
 "protractor": "~5.4.0",
 "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
 "tslint": "~5.15.0",
 "typescript": "~3.5.3"   }
```

Me dice que la versión del paquete no existe. En realidad si existe, pero no puedo solucionar este problema. He intentado borrar la caché de npm, borrar node_module y volver a instalar.
Pero este error me aparece cuando creo una nueva app Angular o cuando quiero modificar la versión de algún package existente.

Comment: Tienes la carpeta **node_modules** creada  ?

Comment: Para crear un nuevo proyecto de angular debes usar `ng new my-dream-app` despues de haber instalado `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Ya hiciste esa parte?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si, para ejecutar los comandos ng debo tener el angular/cli instalado.

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO no, ya que este error me impide instalar los paquetes

Answer (score 0):

Instalé la versión del paquete desde el [tgz](https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz)

En vez de ejecutar npm install source-map@0.6.1

Lo instalé a través de npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz